# How to convert pounds to kilograms in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to figure out how to print an output of pounds or kilograms based on the input, here's my code:

```
def conversion():
    amount = input("Please specify the amount: ")
    if type(amount) is int:
        print "derp"
    answer = raw_input("Please choose between converting FROM kilograms/pounds: ")
    if answer == "kilograms":
        return amount * 2.2 
    elif answer == "pounds":
        return amount / 1.45
    else:
        print "Please choose between kilograms and pounds."
        restart = raw_input("Try again? ")
        if restart == "yes":
            conversion()
            return 0
        elif restart == "y":
            conversion()
            return 0 
        else:
            print "Okay, bye."
            return
finalresult = conversion()
print "the final result is", finalresult
```

Comment: You should try code-formatting this so it's easier to read. Just click on the {} button when selecting it all

Comment: its a conversions calculator so i was wondering how to make it like: 3.576 kilograms versus just 3.576

Comment: This seems to work fine. What problem exactly are you having?

Comment: so you want to strip all of the non-numeric characters? ('3.576 kilograms' to 3.576?)

Answer (score 2):

When you want to return multiple data items from a function in Python, you can return a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) with both data items:

```
return (amount * 2.2, "pounds")
```

or

```
return (amount / 2.2, "kilograms")
```

Modifying your function slightly:

```
def conversion():
    amount = input("Please specify the amount: ")
    if type(amount) is int:
        print "derp"
    answer = raw_input("Please choose between converting FROM kilograms/pounds: ")
    if answer == "kilograms":
        return (amount * 2.2, "pounds")
    elif answer == "pounds":
        return (amount / 2.2, "kilograms")
    else:
        print "Please choose between kilograms and pounds."
        restart = raw_input("Try again? ")
        if restart == "yes":
            conversion()
            return 0
        elif restart == "y":
            conversion()
            return 0 
        else:
            print "Okay, bye."
            return
finalresult = conversion()
print "the final result is: ", finalresult[0], finalresult[1]
```

Note that I also fixed your pounds->kilograms routine:

```
$ python /tmp/convert.py 
Please specify the amount: 10
derp
Please choose between converting FROM kilograms/pounds: kilograms
the final result is:  22.0 pounds
$ python /tmp/convert.py 
Please specify the amount: 22
derp
Please choose between converting FROM kilograms/pounds: pounds
the final result is:  10.0 kilograms
```

Those `return 0` calls will still bung things up :) I expect you should just remove those. Further refinements would be separating the interface code from the conversion routine; your functions should *probably* look more like this:

```
def from_kilograms(kilos):
    return kilos * 2.2
def from_pounds(pounds):
    return pounds / 2.2
def conversation():
    while true:
        ans = raw_input("kg or lb: ")
        num = raw_input("mass: ")
        if ans == "kg"
           print from_kilograms(int(num)), " pounds"
        elsif ans == "lb"
           print from_pounds(int(num)), " kilograms"
        else
           print "bye!"
           return
```

This sort of separation makes it easier to re-use your functions in web server software, a GUI, an ncurses CLI, or plain old terminal CLI.

Comment: @Work, oh yes, this kind of separation _also_ makes it easier to _write unit tests_ for your functions. :D Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat more complicated but much more flexible version:

```
units = {
    'kg':          ('weight', 1.),
    'kilo':        ('weight', 1.),
    'kilogram':    ('weight', 1.),
    'lb':          ('weight', 2.204),
    'pound':       ('weight', 2.204),
    'tonne':       ('weight', 0.001),
    'carat':       ('weight', 5000.),
    'gram':        ('weight', 1000.),
    'dram':        ('weight', 564.4),
    'ounce':       ('weight', 35.27),
    'grain':       ('weight', 15430.),
    'm':           ('distance', 1.),
    'meter':       ('distance', 1.),
    'kilometer':   ('distance', 0.001),
    'km':          ('distance', 0.001),
    'centimeter':  ('distance', 100.),
    'cm':          ('distance', 100.),
    'meter':       ('distance', 1.),
    'mile':        ('distance', 0.0006214),
    'chain':       ('distance', 0.04971),
    'furlong':     ('distance', 0.004971),
    'league':      ('distance', 0.0002071),
    'foot':        ('distance', 3.281),
    'feet':        ('distance', 3.281),        # irregular plural - must be explicitly specified!
    'inch':        ('distance', 39.37)
}

def getUnit(unit_name):
    if unit_name in units:
        return units[unit_name]
    # recognize regular plural forms
    elif unit_name.endswith('es') and unit_name[:-2] in units:
        return units[unit_name[:-2]]
    elif unit_name.endswith('s') and unit_name[:-1] in units:
        return units[unit_name[:-1]]
    # not found?
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unrecognized unit '{0}'".format(unit_name))

def convert(amt, from_unit, to_unit):
    typeA, numA = getUnit(from_unit)
    typeB, numB = getUnit(to_unit)

    if typeA==typeB:
        return amt * numB / numA
    else:
        raise ValueError("Units are of different types ('{0}' and '{1}')".format(typeA, typeB))

def conversion(s):
    """
    Do unit conversion

    Accepts a string of the form
        "(number) (unitA) [to] (unitB)"

    If unitA and unitB are of the same unit-type, returns the converted value.
    """
    s = s.strip().lower().split()
    if len(s) not in (3, 4):
        raise ValueError("Argument string has wrong number of words (should be three or four)")
    try:
        amt = float(s[0])
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Argument string must start with a number")
    from_unit = s[1]
    to_unit   = s[-1]
    return convert(amt, from_unit, to_unit)

def tryAgain():
    s = raw_input('Try again (Y/n)? ').strip().lower()
    return 'yes'.startswith(s)

def main():
    while True:
        s = raw_input("Convert what? (ex: 10 meters to feet) ")
        try:
            print(": {0}".format(conversion(s)))
        except ValueError, v:
            print v
        if not tryAgain():
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

This can solve problems like "10 tonnes to ounces" or "30 furlongs to feet".

Suggested further additions:

1. Add nanometers as a unit of distance (and test it).
2. Add short tons and stones as units of weight (and test them).
3. Add liters, pints, and barrels as units of volume (and test them).